# How to convert a tokens object into a corpus object

Tags: r, quanteda

I have a [corpus object](https://quanteda.io/reference/corpus.html) that I converted into a [tokens object](https://quanteda.io/reference/tokens.html). I then filtered this object to remove words and unify their spelling.
For my further workflow, I again need a corpus object. How can I construct this from the tokens object?

Comment: What do you mean that you need a "tokenised corpus object"? If you convert your tokens object into a corpus, then it will no longer be tokenised.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake - I need a corpus object that I then transform using [corpus_reshape](https://quanteda.io/reference/corpus_reshape.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could paste the tokens together to return a new corpus.  (Although this may not be the best approach if your goal is to get back to a corpus so that you can use `corpus_reshape()`.)

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1.0
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

txt <- c(
  "This is an example.",
  "This, a second example."
)

corp <- corpus(txt)

toks <- tokens(corp) %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords("en"))
toks
## Tokens consisting of 2 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "example" "."      
## 
## text2 :
## [1] ","       "second"  "example" "."

vapply(toks, paste, FUN.VALUE = character(1), collapse = " ") %>%
  corpus()
## Corpus consisting of 2 documents.
## text1 :
## "example ."
## 
## text2 :
## ", second example ."
```